# How to make my flex slider load fast

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

Hi i use flexslider in my magento project,the slider has totally 3 images and i have text contents which will be displayed over the image,the problem is when i load my site my text contents over the slider is loading first and it takes too much time for the images to load and display,then i found a post in stack overflow and used the following commands to make the slider images load fast

```
    .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {display: block; -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;} 
    .flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

by using the above commands the slider will not wait for all images to be loaded whereas the slider will load as soon as the first image is ready.

though it reduced my loading time by 3 to 5 sec it still takes around 10 to 14 sec to display the slider it looks ugly to see my slider contents load first and then my slider images are loading with a delay of 14 sec is there any way to make my flexslider images & contents load fast and load at same time.

Comment: What's the file size on the images you want to load?

Comment: @john klakegg file size 152KB and dimensions 1363*489

Comment: Something must be very wrong if the site takes up to 14 seconds to load. Could you make a jsfiddle showing your code?